# Let AppBar component render title property of its child

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this setup in my app

```
<App>
  <DynamicView />
</App>
```

`App` should render the title property of its child `DynamicView`.
I've tried

```
<h1>{children[0].props.title}</h1>
```

But that property is empty because the the `DynamicView` is a `connected` Redux component. So the actual react tree looks like this:

```
<App>
  <Connect(DynamicView) ...>
    <DynamicView title="A Title"/>
  </Connect(DynamicView)>
</App>
```

Does `connect` provide a way to access its connected components properties?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can accomplish is by accessing the child's children:

```
<h1>{children[0].props.children[0].props.title}</h1>
```

However, this goes against the [React philosophy](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) of parent components being isolated from their children.

An alternative approach that is more in line with React/Redux principles is to put the title in the redux store (and it looks like you already did that, considering `DynamicView` gets it as a prop). You could make the `App` component a connected component that grabs the title from the store, and passes it as a prop into `App`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
             <div>
                 <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                 <DynamicView />
             </div>
         );
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        title: state.title
    })
)(App);
```

Comment: I thought about putting it in the store, but somehow that smells to me. I thought the title belongs to the view.
So the views with a title dispatch a `app/SET_TITLE` action to the store?

Comment: @philk That approach seems reasonable, that action could be set when the `DynamicView` component loads or updates. The idea is that we always want the render() function of `App` to be a function of `App`'s props, and this would be in line with that philosophy.

Comment: Of course a component could then set the title depending on its internal state/props and just call app/SET_TITLE dynamically while its mounted.
Yeah, I think I will go with the title in the app state.

Comment: One more problem is that if a view/page does not set the title, then its stuck with a stale title. So I guess I would have to listen to route changes and clear the title on each route transition. Any ideas how to do that in a `redux` app?

Comment: You could have another action in each component that unsets the title (by setting it to `null`) that is called when the child component is going to unmount (using `componentWillUnmount`). If `App` sees `null` in the title field, it could render a default generic title: `{this.props.title || 'Generic Title'}` If you want something more advanced, I suggest using something like [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) and [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).

Comment: hmmm I'd like to clutter the apps routes with as less noise as possible. Having in each route component an unmount handling is noise. However I am looking at history.listen now and if I use that in my App wrapping component then I could reset the title whenever the route changes.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting alternative way to do it, however, resetting the title through a history listener and setting the title in the component might also be messy. I would suggest maybe also using a higher order component, which would wrap `DynamicView` with lifecycle methods that control the title. [Something like this.](https://gist.github.com/amsardesai/6c173d6d946f7805773f)

Comment: I wonder how the wrapped component would localize the title. I also tried to set the title as a route property. It works, and needs no listener https://gist.github.com/pke/ca52b90b67b8dc35c81f